# Specify multiple glue packages in Eclipse Cucumber Feature Runner

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cucumber

I am trying to run cucumber feature files using the Cucumber plugin for eclipse. When I setup the run configuration, I specify a glue path to a package containing step defs as follows which which works:

classpath:com.company.path.to.stepdef

however, I have feature files which need to access step def classes in different packages (in different jars). I have tried various permutations to specify multiple packages in the glue field, but it only ever finds the stepdefs in the first package.

Comment: do you have one feature which needs different packages or does each feature need a different package?

Comment: I have multiple features which require stepdefs from a library, and other custom stepdefs from my own project. I know I can get this working by specifying everything in a Junit test, but I don't want to have to run all feature files, or have a to amend a junit test each time i want to run a specific feature. i should be able to run it directly in eclipse.